# Going from two View Controllers to the same View controller, but when pressing back it takes them to the initial View controller that they were in

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift4

I am new to Xcode and Swift 4 so please explain to me like a beginner.

I am developing an app that will help students build engineering experiments. Within the app there are some task that will get them points.The teacher after each task is supposed to go to a 'Score' `ViewController` and add points to the team with the correct answers. What i am trying to do is, that at the view controllers in which the teacher has to add score, a button appears and takes her to the 'Score' `ViewController`. But when she presses back, that takes her to the `InitialViewController` from which she clicked the button.

What i am trying to say is that:

If i have storyboard A   B   C   D ,and A and C have that score button that takes them to the same Storyboard S, when clicking back they go back to the `ViewController` they were initially in.

Hope i explained my issue well...

EDIT:
[diagram of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1DEW.jpg)

Hope this helps to clarify, i want the same back button to go to different ViewControllers, depending on which ViewController i was on when i clicked the score button.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: are you asking how to do this (in which I would suggest a UINavigationController)? Or have you made an attempt and it isn't working (In which case, show what you have tried and what is happening)

Comment: I am asking how to do this? I tried to see how i can do it using UINavigatorController, but i dont know how to make a button take me to a navigator page and then back to my app

Comment: What i am trying to do is create a ViewController page that i can call whenever with a press of a button, separately to my main app, and the with a back button go back to where i left off

Comment: "Hope i explained my issue well..." Unfortunately, no. Maybe a diagram would help.

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully it help. I am sorry if i am being annoying. But i am really struggling to explain my problem

Comment: You are asking how the score VC could go back to two different VCs?

Comment: You should probably start a new question, as this one is old its missed everybody by now.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you need to use the unwindSegue function in your initial view controller and connect the A and C view controllers to it.